Parallelizing the summing of an array in CUDA
I have a large array (more than 100,000 elements) in CUDA that needs to be summed into a single variable. I need this to be as time efficient as possible. What would be the fastest way to do this operation with parallelization with CUDA?
My current algorithm was O(n), but I'm thinking if each thread added together two array elements and repeat this process until there's the final value, then it could be reduced to O(log2n). Am I on to something and how would that be implemented?
__global__ void sumArrayPortionsToArrayElement(const int* dev_addendArray, const int* dev_multiplierArray, int* dev_summation, int addendArraySize) {

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i >= sumArraySize * sumArraySize)
        return;

    atomicAdd(&(dev_summation[i % sumArraySize]), dev_addendArray[i] * dev_multiplierArray[i]);
}

This is my current algorithm. An element of dev_multiplierArray is multiplied by an element of dev_addendArray, and then the result is saved to an element of dev_summation. dev_summation is only √ the size of the other arrays which means the sum of n array elements needs to be added to a single element of dev_summation. What is the fastest way to do this with CUDA parallelization? Is there a way to get rid of the race condition entirely?

The answer that says "If you add 2 contiguous numbers, and save the result, in any of the slots where you save those numbers, you will only have to run, multiple times the same kernel, to keep reducing in 2 power the array's sums" is exactly what I was thinking. However, my confusion is about how this would be implemented. Can you you recursive functions inside a kernel? and what would that recursive function look like? I don't think block reduction will be the most efficient due to the massive number of elements and each block only having 1024 threads, unless I'm misunderstanding how it works

Running N times a reduction kernel is inefficient, especially due to the memory overhead of storing intermediate results. Please don't do that if you care about performance or maintainability.

Why do you do i % addendArraySize? It is expensive and makes no sence to me after the if(i >= addendArraySize) return;

atomicAdd are very efficient for block reduction on quite recent devices (AFAIK since ~Kepler). I do not expect CUB to do better, especially since the input array is big and the operation should be memory bound. However, contention can happen between SM if there are many of them (e.g. high-end devices). For better performance, you need to avoid contention by doing a thread-local reduction : each thread need to add many items locally and then perform the atomicAdd. Note that this reduce the amount of parallelism so CUDA cores may starve (thus chunks need not to be too big).

"Can you you recursive functions inside a kernel?" You can run kernels within kernels (dynamic parallelism) but I strongly advise not to do that since it seems not needed here and it typically makes things more complex and introduce some unwanted overheads. "I don't think block reduction will be the most efficient due to the massive number of elements" Why? "having 1024 threads" 1024 threads/block is quite a lot (~maximum) though memory-bound kernels tends to be faster with many threads/block. Avec many threads/block reduce contention on atomics between SM (due to less atomics needed).

The algorithm you are searching for/describing is called a reduction in parallel programming. It is a quite well-researched and described algorithm. See e.g. the reduction CUDA sample and the corresponding slides describing the optimization process of a reduction over 7 different kernels.

There is also the reductionMultiBlockCG sample and the threadFenceReduction sample which are showing alternative approaches for doing reductions in a single kernel launch.
